# ng-repeat tag is deleting my div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm very new to Angular, so this question might have a simple solution.
I'm trying to create a side panel div filled with image-templates:
**ANGULAR Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.thumbnails = [
                {source:'images/img1.jpg',alt:'birthday image', description:'some description'},
                {source:'images/img2.jpg',alt:'birthday image', description:'some description'},
                {source:'images/img3.jpg',alt:'birthday image', description:'some description'},
                {source:'images/img4.jpg',alt:'birthday image', description:'some description'},
                {source:'images/img5.jpg',alt:'birthday image', description:'some description'},
                {source:'images/img6.jpg',alt:'birthday image', description:'some description'}
            ];
        });
```

and **HTML Code**:

```
<div class="w3-row" ng-app="" ng-controller="ctrl"  >
  <div class="w3-container w3-half" id="tiles" style="height:100%; overflow-y: scroll" >
    <h2>THUMBNAILS</h2>
    <div class="w3-container w3-third" ng-repeat="x in thumbnails">
        <div class="">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{x.source}}" alt="{{x.alt}}" style="width:100%; height:auto">
            <div class="w3-container">
              <h4>{{x.description}}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

and at the end, this is how the page looks like:

```
<div class="w3-container w3-half" id="tiles" style="height:100%; overflow-y: scroll">
    <h2>THUMBNAILS</h2>
    <!-- ngRepeat: x in thumbnails -->  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="w3-row">
      <div class="w3-container w3-half" id="tiles" style="height:100%; overflow-y: scroll" >
        <h2>THUMBNAILS</h2>
        <div class="w3-container w3-third" ng-repeat="x in thumbnails">
          <div class="">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{x.source}}" alt="{{x.alt}}" style="width:100%; height:auto" />
            <div class="w3-container">
              <h4>{{x.description}}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js" />
    <script src="script.js" />
  </body>
</html>
```

It basically had to do with where you defined your `ng-app` and ng-controller`.

Comment: Thax for the fast reply, tho this is not the problem! i made a mistake while copying here !

Comment: It's kinda ironic seeing as the title of the SO post also has/had a spelling mistake.

Comment: You're `ng-app` tag is empty, it should be `ng-app="app"`

Comment: @RichardHamilton, I don't have, I ll try to create an account right now, and share with yo

Comment: @user2517028 And yes, I figured after I pointed it out it would be corrected, haha.

Comment: Alright, I fixed this. I will provide some more details and plunkr in a bit